# Strlen not working properly

Tags: php, string, match, strlen

i'm just making experience on some PHP functions to control some form fields.

I just built a real tiny form to see how can work an OOP form, but i'm experiencing a strange behaviour of strlen command.

Here is the code:

class form and its tiny control

```
class Form {

public $nome = '';

public function __construct() {
    if(isset($_POST['nome'])){
    $this->nome = $_POST['nome'];
    }
}
public function body() {

    return "<form action=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF] method=post>
           <input type=text name=nome value=\"$this->nome\">
           <input type=submit value=INVIA><br>";
    }

  }

class check {

public $nome;

public function __construct() {
    $this->nome = $_POST['nome'];
}

public function controllo() {

    if ( !empty($this->nome) && strlen($this->nome >= 3) ) {
        echo "$this->nome è un nome valido";
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

}

PHP implementation

```
<?php
    require '/classes/class.form';

    if(!isset($_POST['nome'])) {
     $form=new Form();
    echo $form->body();   
    } else {
        $check = new check();
        if (!$check->controllo()) {
            $form2=new Form();
            echo $form2->body();
            echo "c'è un errore nei controlli";

        } else {
            echo "tutto ok!";
        }

    }

    ?>
```

As you see, the check should control if the input text lenght is >=3. If false, the form print out again with the content and with an advise that something is wrong, else it says it's correct.

It happens that if I try with "1" and "2", the control does not make it pass, but when i try with "3", it seems that the script does not match the lenght of the input but its type and it gives me a correct match even if the lenght is a single char.

Moreover, if i try a single alphabetical or a number >3 of alphabetical chars, the control is always false. What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have misplaced your closing parenthesis.
`strlen` should be applied to just the variable `$this->nome`, not to your boolean expression `$this->nome >= 3`.

Your original code: `if (!empty($this->nome) && strlen($this->nome >= 3)) {`

What you intended: `if ( !empty($this->nome)  &&  strlen($this->nome) >= 3 ) {`

Comment: corrected the parenthesis, but the problem is unluckily still there

Comment: @CodeClimber Show updated code in question?

Comment: @CodeClimber Does applying `trim()` to your input help?

Comment: done, sorry but i still have to enter into uses of this site :)

Comment: @CodeClimber By your update, you still haven't set it correctly as this answer shows - so I would believe that is still your problem. ^^

Comment: @faintsignal you were right, i misplaced the parenthesis again! now it  seems to work, thank you! waiting 2 minutes to give you the right answer

Comment: thank you for the number "n" genius who downvoted my question for no reason. This site is fantastic but really stupid on some things it allows to do...

Comment: @CodeClimber if you get an answer to your question, does it matter if it is downvoted? ^^ My guess is the downvote is due to it being a typographical error, but I am not the one who downvoted ^^ (though, I am going to vote to close it for that reason, but that doesn't affect the score of it one way or another really =] )

Comment: I'd love to use this site at full functionality, in exemple to comment instead of giving solid answers because i haven't always a full solution but just a tip. I can't comment until i got some reputation, and a damn downvote just cut my rep. This thing is just stupid on a great site like this.